# Pop back stack without onresume called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I got activity a. then I put b in backsatck and display it;
I want to  call c such that a not called again however I want to pop B from BackStack such that return back from C I want it returns to A.
Here is the scenario:

A->B

C Called: A->C

C closed onback pressed: return back to A

 However When I pop B from backstack (in order to replace it with C) fragment A onResume called and do not allow B to be displayed normally.
I also used:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`
```

However this does not fix the problem.
Here is code for switchFragments:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
            // Only ArticlDetailFragment is added to the back stack.
            if (!(fragment instanceof HomeFragment)
            /* && isItNotification == false */) {
                if (debug == 1)
                    Log.v("DEBUG_TAG", "MainAcitivy switchContent2");

                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            contentFragment = fragment;
        }
```

HomeFragment is what is called A here.

Comment: post how you put fragment b on the stack

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of replacing fragment add them in the backstack :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: what does this addToBackStack(null) does? I mean what is differce with addToBackStack(TAG)?